# entity framework db first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, ef-database-first

I have built my MVC 5 project based on entity framework Database First approach by following video tutorials. But what I have obtained is the model. There is nothing in the app_data folder. I want to obtain the .mdf file as well so that I can deploy the database to the azure.

**Note:** I'm using the server explorer database in VS2013.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you will be getting any .mdf files on app_data folder. 
To deploy your database to Azure:

1. Right click your database on SQL server, then Tasks->Generate Scripts. On scripting options, select sql azure server

[image]

2. Login to your azure account and create a SQL server and run generated script from the portal by clicking the link below:

[image]

3. while creating your EF connection, use the connection string for your Azure Database like:
   [image]

   At the end you should be ready to use your ORM.

Comment: How do I generate scripts again please?notice im using the server explorer on VS2013.My database is there.if I right click on it I don't have tasks-->generate scripts

Comment: Ok, on your server explorer right click to your Data Connection and select "Browse in sql server object explorer". On the new window, select your database to export the model, riht click and select "Extract data-tier application". Rest is simple. extract the generated file and your sql script is inside model.sql

Comment: select your database to export the model??can't see mydatabase